# SELECT DISTINCT YEAR Doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I want to select distinct year from mysql database using doctrine:

it is easy to do this using mysql

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT( year , '%Y') as dates FROM Inscription
```

i don't find how to do this in doctrine documentation, anyone can help?

Comment: Which version of Doctrine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Never use distinct, always use group by instead when you can, like this:

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT( year , '%Y') as dates 
    FROM Inscription 
GROUP BY dates
```

Doctrine documentation on group by is easy to find I think.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement `SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT( year , '%Y') as dates FROM Inscription` can be written in Doctrine as follows:

**A. If you are writing a table method:**

```
class InscriptionTable extends Doctrine_Table {
  /* ... */
  public function getDistinctYears()
  {
    return $this->createQuery('I')
           ->select('DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT( year , '%Y')) years')
           ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
           ->execute();
  }
}
```

**B. If you are writing an inline DQL call:**

```
InscriptionTable::getInstance()->createQuery('I')
                ->select('DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT( year , '%Y')) years')
                ->setHydrationMode(Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY)
                ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this with Doctrine 2 you can use this extension:

Guide:
http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/labs/using-mysqls-date_format-in-doctrine-2-0

The code:
https://github.com/uvd/Doctrine

it works great for me

Answer (score 0):

If you use Postgresql, you will receive:

```
select('SUBSTRING(offer.date_closed, 0, 5)')
```

> function substr(timestamp without time zone integer integer) does not
>   exist

Use instead:

```
select('SUBSTRING(CONCAT(offer.date_closed, \'\'), 0, 5)')
```